# Populando um dicionário de dicionários através de um loop for

Tags: python, loop, pandas, dicionário

To tentando criar um loop para adicionar informações em um dicionário de dicionário. A chave mais externa do dicionário será o nome de um curso, e o valor será outro dicionário, haverão 6 chaves, referentes a forma de ingresso na faculdade, e o valor dessas chave será a média do preço da mensalidade para aquele grupo (curso e forma de entrada)

```
entrada = {}
cursos = {}

for curso in toledo.curso.unique():
    materia = toledo[toledo['curso'] == curso]
    for forma_de_entrada in materia.forma_de_entrada.unique():
        media = materia[materia['forma_de_entrada'] == forma_de_entrada].valor_liquido_da_mensalidade.mean()
        entrada[forma_de_entrada] = media
    cursos[curso] = entrada
```

Até consegui popular o dicionário, porém os valores das médias são iguais para todos os cursos. Também tentei limpar o dicionário entrada depois de ter adicionado ele ao dicionário cursos, mas também não da certo.

Comment: Ninguém teve como ajudar você nessa questão por que o código está incompleto - olhando só o código que você colocou quem está olhando tem que adivinhar que "toledo" é um dataframe do pandas - é importante colocar no código algo "mimamente reprodutível" - inclusive com uma linha que crie um dataframe mínimo com os exemplos de dados que você tem

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer de outra maneira, ao invés de popular um dicionário de outros dicionários, populei ele com objetos groupby.

```
dic = {}

for curso in toledo.curso.unique():
    media_curso = toledo[(toledo['curso'] == curso) & (toledo['status'] == 'matriculado')].groupby('forma_de_entrada')\
                  .valor_liquido_da_mensalidade.mean()
    dic[curso] = media_curso
```

Apesar de eu ter conseguido, queria saber se é possível fazer isso com um dicionário de dicionários, e se tem um jeito melhor para resolver isso.

Valeu.